# Orfeo Toolbox error

Tags: qgis, error, orfeo-toolbox, image-segmentation

I'm using segmentation (mean-shift) tool in Orfeo Toolbox with QGIS
I used a subset of pansharpened image from Worldview3 after orthorectification.
But, I got same error whenever I tried:

```
2020-07-02 00:22:46 (WARNING) Segmentation: The input image has no data values but this application does not handle no-data. No-data pixels will be treated as regular pixels.
```

Could you let me know my fault, pansharpened image is not available for segmentation?

Answer (score 1):

The message you get is not an *error*, but a *warning*. It tells you that the Segmentation application doesn't manage the "no data" value. In [OTB's cookbook](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_Segmentation.html?#limitations), it says that processing images with no data values may lead to unexpected segmentation results and crashes.

When you want to use the Segmentation application on an image with no data, you should first process your image using the [ManageNoData application](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_ManageNoData.html), which is also available in QGIS.